# How could i copy multiple files 1 at a time from 2 folders to another folder with a windows batch file or vbs script

Tags: shell, batch-file

I am working with a video camera and we have a program that displays the saved videos from an SD card when inserted into a PC. At some point the manufacturer of the camera changed the directory structure and naming convention for the saved files. I would like to create a batch file or VBS Script that will reorganize the files into the old structure. This will be a quick and dirty fix for windows based PC's and until we can re-write the software which will include support for MAC's. It can be a batch file or a VBS Script but must run under a Windows command prompt with no additional software installed. The camera has front and rear cameras so there are 2 files to deal with and there could be 1 or more video captures to relocate.

The number of folders would depend on the number of videos saved, let's say there are 4 videos saved so the original structure looked like this.

```
- video1
    - video.TS
    - video2.TS
- video2
    - video.TS
    - video2.TS
- video3
    - video.TS
    - video2.TS
- video4
    - video.TS
    - video2.TS
```

The new structure looks like this

```
- Normal
    - F
        - DATETIME-000001F.TS
        - DATETIME-000002F.TS
        - DATETIME-000003F.TS
        - DATETIME-000004F.TS
    - R
        - DATETIME-000001R.TS
        - DATETIME-000002R.TS
        - DATETIME-000003R.TS
        - DATETIME-000004R.TS
```

The object is to move these files into the older file structure so the software can read and display them. I already have a batch file that runs when the SD card is inserted so my assumption is that I can include some script before the normal process fires to move these files around. I am pretty rusty with scripting and need some guidance.

My current script look like this.

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set count=0
for %%x in (\Normal\F\*.TS) do (
set /a count += 1
mkdir video!count!
move /Y \Normal\F\*.TS \video!count!\video.TS
move /Y \Normal\R\*.TS \video!count!\video2.TS
)
endlocal
```

There are always 2 videos, 1 for the front camera and 1 for the rear camera so I am only using the "F" directory to get the count.

Without the move commands it creates the directory structure just fine... If there is 1 file it only creates 1 folder, if there are 8 files it creates 8 folders. but when there are multiple files it wants to put all of the files in the first folder.
I assume I would need to nest another loop but everything I have tried has failed and this is the closest attempt.

Comment: Tip: `%%x` is one file at a time, so you can copy one file at a time: `move /Y "%%x" "video!count!\video.TS`. Add a second loop for the rear files (lazy method) or use substring manipulation (`set /?`) to replace the `\F\` with `\R\` and copy the rear files within the same loop..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following settings for the source directory, destination directory, target directory,
rem batch directory, filenames, output filename and temporary filename [if shown] are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.
SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"


FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\normal\F\*-*.ts" '
 ) DO (
  SET "video2=%%~na"
  SET "video2=!video2:~0,-1!R%%~xa"
  FOR /f "tokens=2delims=.-" %%i IN ("%%a") DO (
   SET "video=%%i"
   SET /a video=1!video:~0,-1!-1000000
   MD "%destdir%\video!video!" 2>NUL
   MOVE /y "%sourcedir%\normal\F\%%a" "%destdir%\video!video!\video.TS" >NUL 2>nul
   MOVE /y "%sourcedir%\normal\R\!video2!" "%destdir%\video!video!\video2.TS" >NUL 2>nul

  )
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the values assigned to `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances. The listing uses a setting that suits my system.

I deliberately include spaces in names to ensure that the spaces are processed correctly.

First, assign to `%%a` each filename found in the `...\F` directory.

Then construct the corresponding filename in `...\R` by taking the name part of `%%a`, removing the last character and replacing it with `R`, then appending the extension from `%%a`.

Next, derive the sequence number from `%%a` by selecting the second token from `%%a` using `-` and `.` as delimiters. Set the number part of the destination directoryname by prefixing all bar the last character of `video` with `1` and subtracting 1000000 to convert it to the natural form.

Create the destination directory and move in and rename the source files

[edit in response to comments]

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "drives=d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z"
SET "sourcedir=normal"
:: locate drive that has directory "?:\normal\f"
FOR %%d IN (%drives%) DO IF EXIST "%%d:\%sourcedir%\f\." SET "sourcedir=%%d:\%sourcedir%"&SET "destdir=%%d:\video"&GOTO founddrive
ECHO Could not find "%sourcedir%\f" on any drive
GOTO :eof

:founddrive
SET /a destnum=1
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\f\*-*.ts" '
 ) DO (
 MD "%destdir%!destnum!" 2>NUL
 SET "filename=%%~na"
 set "filename=!filename:~0,-1!R%%~xa"
 MOVE /y "%sourcedir%\F\%%a" "%destdir%!destnum!\video.TS" >NUL 2>nul
 MOVE /y "%sourcedir%\R\!filename!" "%destdir%!destnum!\video2.TS"  >NUL 2>nul
 SET /a destnum+=1
)

GOTO :EOF
```

OK, so this version first scans for the directoryname, then picks the files and places them, with namechanges, in directory `video1...` on the same drive.

Comment: thanks for responding on new years day, this is very close. i am getting directories 
video-888720
video-888735
video-888740
and the last directory only had 1 of the TS files. it was left in the the original Normal\R directory and not copied. 
would really like to have it in 
video1
video2 
video3 etc. 
and include that last file

Comment: also these files will always be in the root of an SD card BUT i wont know what the drive letter is as it could be in any computer, i am assuming i can do without the %sourcedir% and %destdir% and just use 
 MD "\video!video!" 2>NUL
with out any adverse consequences

Comment: Well, 'ts January 2nd here - 5am or so... I've no explanation why the very last file failed the `move` instruction - The only conceivable explanation I can fathom is that the file was open at the time. If you remove the `>nul 2>nul` from the `move` line, a report should be generated to screen which might yield a clue. Or you could duplicate the `move` lines and replace the `move /y` with `echo` and remove the now-`echo` lines' `>nul 2>nul` which suppress the messages-to-screen and error-messages-to-screen, respectively.

Comment: directories are perfect! the last file was my fault, in the R directory i had 2 files with the same time/date stamp. in my testing i had manually copied that file from another. this would never happen in production. thank you for your help.